# Is $1=1$ tautology?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is "1=1" tautology ?

In this case, "1" means multiplicative identity of real number.

If we treat "1=1" as a simple proposition p , we will get p is not tautology.

But p is always true because it denotes "1=1" which is always true

Can we say that "1=1" is tautology?

Comment: Define a tautology.

Comment: In most developments of first order logic $x=x$ is a theorem for any $x$. But as Kenny says, it depends on what you mean by *tautology*. In the sense that any formula having the same arrangement of truth functional operators is true, then clearly not. In the sense that it's true regardless of any extralogical axioms, sure.

Comment: See [tautology (logic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) : "In logic, a tautology is a formula or assertion that is true in every possible interpretation. A formula of propositional logic is a tautology if the formula itself is always true regardless of which valuation is used for the propositional variables." Thus, you have two possible readings: the narrow one, restricting the use of the term to propositional logic, and the wider one, regarding logic in general. According to the wider reading, it is a tautology, because it is an instance of the valid FOL formula: $x=x$.

Comment: In classical logic, it is a tautology, but there may be some logics where it's not (actually, there are - but are they interesting ?)

Comment: Whether something is formally a tautology or not depends on your logic.  So this question cannot be answered without more information.  In bare bones FOL, no it isn't tautology because $=$ could be an empty relation.  In an Arithmetic Logic yes it will be a tautology because it doesn't contain any variables and computes correctly.  So as it is, this question can't be answered.

Answer (score 2):

See [tautology (logic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) :

> "In logic, a tautology is a formula or assertion that is true in every possible interpretation. A formula of propositional logic is a tautology if the formula itself is always true regardless of which valuation is used for the propositional variables."

Thus, we have two possible readings: the narrow one, restricting the use of the term to propositional logic, and the wider one, regarding logic in general.

According to the wider reading, it is a tautology, because it is an instance of the valid first-order logic formula: $x=x$.