# Is every theorem a tautology?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Depending on the proof of a theorem, there are actually 3 questions:

1. For a proof without premise $\vdash c$, is c a tautology?
2. For a proof with premises $p_1,p_2,...,p_n \vdash c$, is $p_1\land p_2,...,\land p_n\to c$ a tautology?
3. For a proof with premises and axioms $p_1,p_2,...,p_n,a_1,a_2,...,a_m \vdash c$, is $p_1\land p_2...\land p_n\land a_1\land a_2...\land a_m\to c$ a tautology?

As a logic beginner, I'm not sure if I'm really clear about the concepts such as axiom, tautology, and theorem, so I want a "yes" or "no" answer to my question. And I heard people talk about "logically valid". Is that the same as tautology?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867706/is-1-1-tautology).